# Remove SSE2 intrinsics in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, intrinsics

Does anyone know how to remove all SSE2 intrinsics from sources (in Visual C++)? There are probably a few at some places, since I have been using SSE2. Now I'd like to move my project to SSE again. I wonder if I could #define something to find them with one compile.

Thanks for your help @ Heandel and Necrolis

I did it indeed by hand with find "_mm_"... sort... and then looking up each.

Answer (score 1):

The definitions for all of the functions are in `intrin.h` (xmmintrin.h and emmintrin.h might also be used), so just comment out all the inclusions of that header and use the compilers undefined symbol errors to find them(some other intrinsics may also get thrown in there).